# CSS background image slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
.banner {
    background: url(images/im1.jpg) center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.banner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 74px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 1582px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
.inner-banner {
    background: url(images/im1.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
```

How to slide im1 to im6 automatically?
I also want to add that small round button on the bottom of the image so that it moves easily.

Comment: have a look at this example... https://codeconvey.com/css-background-image-slider/

Comment: could you please past minimal code to reproduce the problem statment.